# Integral related to standard normal distributon

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution

Suppose $Z' \sim N(0,1)$ but we observe $Z=Z'$ when $Z' \in (l, u)$ otherwise we do not see $Z'$ at all. We use $\phi$ and $\Phi$ to represent standard normal pdf and cdf. Please calculate $$\int_{l}^{u} z \frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(u)-\Phi(l)}\,{\rm d}z$$

I know the integral of $\phi(z)$ will be $1$? How can I proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\Phi(u)-\Phi(l)$ is a constant, so we can take it out of the integral. We have $$\int_l^uz\cdot \frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(u)-\Phi(l)}\,{\rm d}z=\frac{1}{\Phi(u)-\Phi(l)}\int _l^uz\phi(z)\,{\rm d}z$$
Recall the standard normal pdf: $$\phi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12z^2\right)$$
Now the integral becomes $$\frac{1}{\Phi(u)-\Phi(l)}\int _l^uz\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12z^2\right)\,{\rm d}z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\Phi(u)-\Phi(l))}\int_l^uz\exp\left(-\frac12z^2\right)\,{\rm d}z$$
Letting $u=-\frac12z^2,\:{\rm d}u=-z\,{\rm d}z$, \begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\Phi(u)-\Phi(l))}\int_l^uz\exp\left(-\frac12z^2\right)\,{\rm d}z&= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\Phi(u)-\Phi(l))}\int_{-\frac12l^2}^{-\frac12u^2}\exp(u)\,{\rm d}u\\
&= \frac{\exp\left(-\frac12l^2\right)-\exp\left(-\frac12u^2\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\Phi(u)-\Phi(l))}
\end{align*}
which gives your desired result.